# Video timeline in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

I'm trying to make a video timeline with SwiftUI. In particular, I want the user to be able to drag a video horizontally to move in time.

In order to do so, I have programmed the following code:

```
ZStack {

  Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.black)
    .frame(height: 350)

  VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
     HStack(spacing: 5) {
        Button(action: {
           print("Undo")
        }) {
           Image(systemName: "arrow.turn.up.left")
             .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
             .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
        Button(action: {
           print("Add media")
        }) {
           Image(systemName: "plus")
              .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
              .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
     }
     .offset(x: 110)
     .padding(.horizontal, 10)
     .padding(.top, 10)

     HStack(spacing: 60) {
       Text("00:00").foregroundColor(Color.white)
       Text("00:02").foregroundColor(Color.white)
       Text("00:04").foregroundColor(Color.white)
       Text("00:06").foregroundColor(Color.white)
      }
     .offset(x: xOffset)

     Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.black)
        .frame(height: 85)

     HStack(spacing: 5) {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(Color.gray)
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60)
          .cornerRadius(8)

        Rectangle()
          .fill(Color.gray)
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: 60)
          .cornerRadius(8)
      }
      .offset(x: xOffset)

      Rectangle()
         .fill(Color.black)
         .frame(height: 130)
    }
    .gesture(
       DragGesture()
         .onChanged({ value in
            xOffset = value.location.x
         })
         .onEnded({ _ in
            print(xOffset)
         })
     )
   }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDEO.png)

The problem is that when you click on the timeline and drag, the gray rectangle moves to the cursor position. And in reality, what I want is that when you click on the timeline and drag, the displacement that you do when dragging should move the gray rectangle. For example, if I click at x = 100 and drag to x = 90, the gray rectangle should move x = -10. Something like this:

[Demo 2](https://www.cyberlink.com/prog/learning-center/html/15975/PDR19-YouTube-775_PDRM-%2010%20Best%20Video%20Splitter%20Apps/img/split%20video%20UI%20of%20PowerDirector_2.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `location` to `transition` in `value.location.x`

And then you can try it again.

Comment: I had to to do this: `.gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in xOffset = xStartOffset + value.translation.width }).onEnded({ _ in xStartOffset = xOffset print(xOffset) }))` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: That's correct to add `xStartOffset`, glad to hear that :)